# A question about integrable function.

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

**My question:**

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{U}, \mu)$ be a measure space, and let $X$ be an integrable function and let $A, \ \ \{A_n\} \in \mathscr{U}; n\in \Bbb N$.

How to prove that $$\int_{A_n} X d\mu \to_{n\to \infty} \int_A X d\mu $$

if

$$\mu (A_n \Delta A)\to_{n\to \infty} 0$$

---

**My solution trails**

$(A_n \Delta A)=(A_n \setminus A )\cup (a \setminus A_n)=(A_n \cap A^c)\cup (A \cap A_n^c)$

$=(A_n \cup A)\cap (A_n \cap A)^c$

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu (A_n \Delta A) =0$

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu [(A_n \cup A)\cap (A_n \cap A)^c]=0 $

$(A_n \Delta A)= (A_n \cup A)\cap (A_n \cap A)^c$  is the set of points that belong to either set but not to both.

Since $X$ is integrable, we can write

$$\int X_{1A} d\mu = \int_A X d\mu$$

but I could not figure out how to show;

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int X_1 A_n d\mu =\int X_{1A} d\mu$$

But I'm stuck. please help me :((

Answer (score 2):

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Since $X$ is integrable, there exists $R>0$ such that

$$\int_{|X| \geq R} |X| \, d\mu < \epsilon.$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align*} \left| \int_{A_n} X \, d\mu - \int_A X \, d\mu \right| &= \left| \int (1_{A_n}-1_A) X \, d\mu \right| \\ &\leq 2 \int_{|X| \geq R} |X| \, d\mathbb{P} + \int_{|X|<R} |1_{A_n}-1_A| \cdot |X| \, d\mu \\ &\leq 2 \epsilon + R \mu(A_n \Delta A). \end{align*}$$

Since this holds for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mu(A_n \Delta A) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, this implies

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left| \int_{A_n} X \, d\mu - \int_A X \, d\mu \right| \leq 2 \epsilon.$$

As $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we conclude

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \int_{A_n} X \, d\mu - \int_A X \, d\mu \right|=0.$$